# What is the purpose of LatLngBounds in GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions()?

Tags: android, google-places-api

What is `LatLngBounds` object used for in Google Places Autocomplete API?

.. and/or what does it mean by :

> ***biasing the results to a specific area*** specified by latitude and longitude bounds

?

In the Google Places Autocomplete docs, it says to pass in `LatLngBounds` and `AutocompleteFilter` .

```
PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> result =
    Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(
        mGoogleApiClient, query, bounds, autocompleteFilter);
```

In using the Places Autocomplete, I can see how the AutocompleteFilter restricts results, say by country.  What's not clear is how `LatLngBounds` is being used.  In the example code there is this for the Bounds object:

```java
private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = 
                    new LatLngBounds(
                    new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), 
                    new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));
```

It says the bound is to Mountain View (a city in SF Bay Area California), yet I can still get results for other countries when filter is null.

From this resource:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

> Your app can get a list of predicted place names and/or addresses from the autocomplete service by calling GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(), passing the following parameters:
>
> Required: A **LatLngBounds** object, biasing the results to a specific area specified by latitude and longitude bounds.
>
> Optional: An **AutocompleteFilter** containing a set of place types, which you can use to restrict the results to one or more types of place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you want to search Cafe The Coffee Day, If you set `LatLngBounds` result will be display according to that location.

E.g If you set `LatLngBounds` in **New York** and you search cafe coffee day, you will see results of **New York**. If you set `LatLngBounds` of **Sydney** you will see results of **Sydney**.

Now If you want to set `LatLngBounds` to your location, then you have to get current location and set `LatLngBounds` according to that.

You can also specify **radius** for getting a specific result.

**For Example**.

I am using below code to get result of my current city.

```
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mAdapter;
AutoCompleteTextView autoTextViewPlace;

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();

// I am getting Latitude and Longitude From Web API

if((strLatitude != null && !strLatitude.trim().isEmpty()) && (strLongitude != null && !strLongitude.trim().isEmpty())){
        LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(strLatitude), Double.parseDouble(strLongitude));
        if(currentLatLng != null){
                setLatlngBounds(currentLatLng);
        }
}

public void setLatlngBounds(LatLng center){

        double radiusDegrees = 0.10;
        LatLng northEast = new LatLng(center.latitude + radiusDegrees, center.longitude + radiusDegrees);
        LatLng southWest = new LatLng(center.latitude - radiusDegrees, center.longitude - radiusDegrees);
        LatLngBounds bounds = LatLngBounds.builder().include(northEast).include(southWest).build();

        mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), mGoogleApiClient, bounds,
                null);
        autoTextViewPlace.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding exactly, since I was able to see results outside the bound still.  Does it mean - if there are 2 cafes with the same name in Australia and New York, then setting the `LatLngBounds` to be inside New York but NOT having filter restricting the country - then this means the New York cafe will come up first .. but the one in Australia will still come up with lower priority?

Comment: See my updated code., In my case Its working as expected. Have you set radiusDegrees ?

Comment: Nice example code there.  I was just using `LatLngBounds` object as defined in the example with `BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW` .  My requirement is to search at least nation wide - so when it says the Bounds are for just 1 city, my concern is that the bounds object will make the search radius too small.  However I can still see NY City come up , even if the local business in California **New York Pizza** (closer to the Mountain View bounds) comes up before **NY City, USA**.  I guess this is what the docs mean by *"**biasing** the results"* .. vs. the notion of actually ***restricting*** those results

Comment: Do you recommend any good docs on understanding how to determine/apply `radiusDegrees`? Thanks